# Outline of the Ear needed using "boundary" function of matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, mesh, boundary, vertices

I am trying to work work with a 3D head mesh data which is in .PLY formart. My goal is to extract certain features of this 3D head mesh like head and Ear parameters. I have attached one image of this mesh in 3D view. (trisurf method of Matlab)
My approach was to first get outline of interest of the mesh, and then extract points and hence extract measurers, for example head width. I was successful with the head parameters.
What is challenging is to get outline of the ear. I am using "boundary" function of matlab to get outline of the mesh, but it is not able to detect outline of the ear. Of course, when seen the mesh from the front view, you can see the ears, but what is important to me is to get outline of the ear and its other features from the side view. I have attached the image of side view, where ear outline is not visible.

Please can anyone help me? How do I get outline of the ear using boundary or some other function of matlab?
[image: 3D Head Mesh]
[image: Side View with no ear outline]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you manually click some points along the ear and make a spline passing through them?